# Multiple MYSQLi prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am just learning how to use MYSQLi prepared statements so please go easy on me. I can get these to work individually but when I put them together they don't work.

```
$con = my connection details.
```

This is my code for the queries:

```
// Insert the review into DB 
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO reviews (order_id, comment) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('is', $order_id, $comment);
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->close();


// Update transactions to show review added
$stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE transactions SET review = ? WHERE order_id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ii', 1, $order_id);
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->close();
```

Thanks in advance for your help! Much appreciated.

Comment: "Here is the code, go fix it for me" is not the kind of question Stack Overflow intended for. *At least* some effort in describing what's going on an how it is "not work" is expected.

Comment: @user3170837: regarding your last (deleted) post. If you don't like someone's comment contribution, ignore it or report to moderator as appropriate. I would be mildly of the view that the deleted question was on-topic, since it is not substantial enough for _Code Reivew_, but we try to avoid questions that are excessively localised too. It's a difficult balance.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Halfer, I didn't know there was such a function to report a comment on this site. Moreover, thanks for your help on the type/style of questions that I should ask next time. **+1** for support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is good however you shouldn't name them the same name `$stmt`

The first statement is `$stmt`

Then give the second statement another name, like `$stmt2` or whatever name you like.

**example:**

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO reviews (order_id, comment) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('is', $order_id, $comment);
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->close();


// Update transactions to show review added
$stmt2 = $con->prepare("UPDATE transactions SET review = ? WHERE order_id = ?");
$stmt2->bind_param('ii', 1, $order_id);
$stmt2->execute(); 
$stmt2->close();
```

and to debug your code and see where the error(s) is/are use this.

```
if ($stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO reviews (order_id, comment) VALUES (?, ?)") ){
   $stmt->bind_param('is', $order_id, $comment);
   $stmt->execute(); 
   $stmt->close();
    }
 else {printf("Error message:: %s\n", $con->error);}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use $stmt2, but if you are already closing $stmt there is no need to use $stmt2. Once you have closed $stmt you are free to use it again